# Use of as many as in two different sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

> I hope that you read books as many as I do.
>
> I hope that you read as many books as I do.

What is the difference between two sentences. I thought first one means that I read books and I want you to read as much as I do. And second one means You read books which are in the amount that I read.

Comment: "Book" is a countable noun, so "as much books" is wrong and must be "as many books." And this yields a clue about the difference: "much" in the first sentence applies to "read," not to "books."

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is not correct.

> I hope that you read books as many as I do.

Structured like this it doesn't make any sense, bceause "as many" appears to be operating on the verb "to read" when actually it refers to the number of books. You could say "I hope you read books *as often* as I do", because "as often" is the frequency with which you read.

> I hope that you read as many books as I do.

This simply means you hope the other party reads the same number of books as you do.

Comment: Both of the OP's sentences originally said "much" but they were both changed to "many" in response to my comment, which was apparently misunderstood.